# How can I record the voice at the same time of playing sound in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, audio, audio-recording

I am working on app called "Parnk Call" who has features that already saved recordings start playing on calllayout when user click the pick button while on the same time I can also want to record the voice from mic ?

Can you tell me the classes which we used fro recording and playing?
Because I cann't figure out is MediaRecorder, AudioRecorder  helpful for recording ?
And for the playing sound soundpool or mediaplayer ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Android documentation and analyze which of the multiple ways of doing recording and playing in android is suitable to what your app needs. In my app, this worked for me:

For playing:

```
AudioTrack fAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(STREAM_MUSIC, fs, CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 2*playbuffer.length, MODE_STATIC);

fAudioTrack.play();
//check the status through setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener

when finished (check inside onMarkerReached)
fAudioTrack.flush();
fAudioTrack.stop();
fAudioTrack.release();
```

For recording:

```
int _Min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(fs, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
AudioRecord fAudioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, fs, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 2*_Min);

fAudioRecord.startRecording();
//loop several times until you want to stop recording or a certain time of recording has passed and within the loop
samplesRecordedSoFar = fAudioRecord.read(tempHWRecBuffer, offsetTempHWRecBuffer, maximumSamplesAtOnce);

//when you're done
fAudioRecord.stop();
fAudioRecord.release();
```